# Is there a list of Ubuntu-compatible laptops?

Tags: laptop, hardware, compatibility

Is there an updated list of current laptops which have been found to work well under Ubuntu (other than the common "n best linux laptops of YYYY" articles)?  There appears to be a page for [Ubuntu-certified hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/) but laptops are not among the categories of hardware listed.

Comment: What about here: https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/

Comment: Ohhhhhhh they mean "certified to run the Ubuntu Desktop configuration of the operating system".  Ahhhhh.  Thanks.  Sort of a confusing way to organize their website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At [the page you linked](https://certification.ubuntu.com/), look under "[Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/)" There is a list of desktops *and* laptops.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking this [list](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/) is an up to date compilation of the latest Ubuntu compatible laptops and desktops.